# Ressource consumption when sending data from AWS Greengrass to the AWS Cloud

Tags: mqtt, amazon-kinesis, aws-iot-greengrass, aws-iot-core

I'm currently working on a project where we are using AWS Iot Greengrass on an edge device to measure some metrics coming from a machine. We have a Kinesis Analytics application running to detect some anomalies in the data. My problem is that I really don't know how to efficiently send the data to the aws cloud with a mostly low memory foodprint.

I see in the greengrass sdk when I use the `IotDataClient` (we are using pyhton) every invocation on `publish` is calling internally the a lambda function. I fear (we need to send at approx 500-1000 datapoints/s) that this might kill the edge device and utilise high cpu consumption.

The other way is to use the `StreamManager` which might be a better fit for high volume data but I'm not sure if this is a little overkill since it brings a java process to the device. Also I cannot publish to MQTT and I'm tied to AWS Kinesis or other managed services.

Does anyone have the experience with loading this amount of of data via greengrass to the AWS Cloud?

Comment: Test it, it's the only way to be sure with your specific setup.

Comment: but it seems more specific to aws in this case. As far as I know mqtt protocol can easily handle this amount of data

Comment: But it's going to be specific to your choice of edge device, your specific messages and the network connection.

Comment: true that. I'm just curious if there are any experiences with some kind of setup

Comment: Test, test and retest. Else, failure. See this video for one test that seems relevant https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxA1CmZrVyM